# problems when i install node-inspector in win7

Tags: node.js, installation, node-inspector

When i try to install node-inspector,some problems happen. But it also creat a file named node-inspector.!.When i try to use node-inspector it shows"debugger listening on port 5858",and there is not show "suceess!" .Just like the third picture ! I don't know how to deal with this problem!
Below is the infomation:

```
> ws@0.4.32 install C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! ws@0.4.32 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.32 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-inspector" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Program Files\nodejs>^A

C:\Program Files\nodejs>cd\

C:\>node --debug-brk=5858 getmodule.js
debugger listening on port 5858
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have compiler tools installed and configured:

- Python (v2.7.3 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
- Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop (Express version works too)

See e.g. these [instructions](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLA/Installing+compiler+tools) for more details.

Comment: I hava installed Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012,but it still dosen't work .It shows the same error as before.